# Где можно найти курсы/учителя/репетитора по SpriteKit?

Tags: swift, spritekit

я изучил вполне не плохо язык swift и приступил к изучению spriteKit нашел очень немного видео уроков, передающих в принципе схожую информацию, я их посмотрел, но что мне делать дальше? Где учиться теперь? больше вообще практически обучающих уроков нет, искал репетиторов на сайтах - везде только просто учителя swift но никто не берется за spriteKit? Помогите пожалуйста, есть ли где то хорошие курсы или учителя и где продолжить обучение SpriteKit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ищите вот такую книжку: 2D Apple Games by Tutorials с примерами проектов

https://store.raywenderlich.com/products/2d-apple-games-by-tutorials